# How to clear the form after submitting the values?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

I have a form with few filed. Once i submit the form the data is stored in database and i will return to the same page.
Now, How to clear the fields in the form??

It is a struts based application. On submit it does some validations using java script then forwarded to the same page. Now, I must get a fresh page. I mean the fields must be cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override Struts' Action `reset()` method and after you used it in your action you can do `form.reset(request, response);` and do a forward. That way, your form is resetted.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the javascript `reset()` method on the form?

Comment: doesn't reset reset the values to their default state? ie, what they were on page load? ie, this will do nothing, not to mention there's no reason to have to do this with js

Comment: @Mark - it will reset them to what they are defined as in their `value` attribute.  It depends on whether the fields are being set via their attributes or via javascript.

Comment: @bernace: unless struts is really weird (i've never used it), it'll set the `value` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 options use on load JavaScript form.reset() or you can clear your formclass fields before returning to your form ie define a reset method in your struts form class call this method before return.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the form with the **reset** method of your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect method like this :

```
request.setStatus(request.SC_SEE_OTHER);
request.setHeader("Location",url);
```

Where SC_SEE_OTHER is the proper 303 code and "url" is the url of you current page this will reload your page so all your filed will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i handle in java action class , you should clear the model or bean object in your java class before return Action.SUCCESS;
example
customerDetail.setId("");
customerDetail.setName("");